# Zend Framework - URL's not working

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, mod-rewrite

I uploaded my site to the live environment and the default index/index works just fine. I have filtered out the index.php file using

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

When I type in the direct route `mysite.com/index/index` into the browser I get a 404 page. Typing `mysite.com/index.php/index/index` results in 'No input file specified.' message. 
I get these same messages when visiting any other of my sites URL's. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: What web server software is your live environment using? If Apache, where are those rewrite rules placed (`.htaccess`, `httpd.conf`, etc)?

Comment: Not an htaccess guru - does the last line need an escape? `RewriteRule ^.*$ index\.php [NC,L]`?

Answer (score 0):

The rules are right. The .htaccess must be in the public folder. Finally check that there're no other .htaccess (for example in the parent directory of public).

Answer (score 0):

make sure the mod_rewrite is enabled and all calls to the mysite.com should be redirected to the /public/index.php file

Answer (score 0):

Also change 'AllowOveride none' to 'AllowOveride All' in vhost.conf